# Made copy of controller and re-named the original controller, production environment used old renamed controller?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, arrays, ruby-on-rails-3

I wanted a backup of my controller so I could make a new one with a new feature. I made a copy of the original and re-named the original. Like this: tickets_controller_9_18_2013.rb
When I added my new feature in index to the new copied controller that is named as the original controllers name: tickets_controller.rb the development env. used the new feature controller with the original name 'tickets_controller.rb' while the production env. used the re-named original controller 'tickets_controller_9_18_2013.rb'
How do you make the production env. use the copied one that is renamed as the original?

In my controller I am getting all the Users that have the same 'reseller_id' attribute.
Then I am putting the tickets from each user into and array @tickets.

```
class Users::TicketsController < ApplicationController

def index
    if admin_user?
    @tickets = []
    all_users = User.find_all_by_reseller_id(current_user.reseller_id)
    all_users.each do |u|
      @tickets += u.tickets
    end
  @tickets = @tickets.paginate(page: params[:page])
  else
   @tickets = current_user.tickets.paginate(page: params[:page])
end
```

The problem is during production environment the array is not the same as the development environment.
I have restarted the apache server and checked for any before_filter s.

Any ideas as to why the results are different?

Below are the logs from both environments when loading the array.

```
PRODUCTION

Processing by Users::TicketsController#index as HTML 
User Load (0.1ms) SELECT `users`.* FROM `users` WHERE `users`.`remember_token` = 'kaVFM4TddpFadAP8w12Iwg' LIMIT 1 
Reseller Load (0.1ms) SELECT `resellers`.* FROM `resellers` WHERE `resellers`.`id` = 1 LIMIT 1 
Rendered users/_info.html.erb (1.8ms) 
Rendered layouts/_opentag.html.erb (0.1ms) 
Ticket Load (0.1ms) SELECT `tickets`.* FROM `tickets` WHERE `tickets`.`user_id` = 1 LIMIT 30 OFFSET 0 
Rendered users/tickets/index.html.erb within layouts/application (5.9ms) 
Rendered layouts/_header.html.erb (0.0ms) 
Rendered layouts/_footer.html.erb (0.1ms)


DEVELOPMENT

Processing by Users::TicketsController#index as HTML 
User Load (0.1ms) SELECT `users`.* FROM `users` WHERE `users`.`remember_token` = 'E0_tHb5p-7XTZAB8XcxtGg' LIMIT 1 
User Load (0.1ms) SELECT `users`.* FROM `users` WHERE `users`.`reseller_id` = 1 
Ticket Load (0.1ms) SELECT `tickets`.* FROM `tickets` WHERE `tickets`.`user_id` = 1 
Ticket Load (0.1ms) SELECT `tickets`.* FROM `tickets` WHERE `tickets`.`user_id` = 6 
Ticket Load (0.1ms) SELECT `tickets`.* FROM `tickets` WHERE `tickets`.`user_id` = 7 
Reseller Load (0.1ms) SELECT `resellers`.* FROM `resellers` WHERE `resellers`.`id` = 1 LIMIT 1 
Rendered users/_info.html.erb (2.3ms) 
Rendered layouts/_opentag.html.erb (0.1ms) 
Rendered users/tickets/index.html.erb within layouts/application (67.9ms) 
Rendered layouts/_header.html.erb (0.0ms) 
Rendered layouts/_footer.html.erb (0.1ms)
```

If I add the code to re-named original 'tickets_controller_9_18_2013.rb' the production env. uses it and the feature works.
How do I use the new controller named as the original? 'tickets_controller.rb'
Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had to place the date in front of the original name like this:

```
09_13_2013_tickets_controller.rb
```

Instead of:

```
tickets_controller_09_19_2013.rb
```

I had no idea that mattered.

Comment: That worked because you have two files with the same class defined in them. In ruby it is legal to define a single class in multiple files. Ruby sees one single combined class. But when you have same method defined in multiple places (for the same class), I guess load path matters.

Answer (score 1):

You should restart your application in production. Rails caches classes in production mode. To reload the classes, restart the application.

Comment: I just renamed it to have the date in the front and it worked. 9_18_2013_tickets_controller.rb worked.